How can I flatten my floor prior to LVP installation?
I want to install this LVP in my basement. I plan to use this underlay. Currently the basement floor is linoleum adhered to concrete. Pics here. There is an area where the floor dips about 1/2 inch over a 1 foot radius (I think the low spot is because the floor drain is nearby on the other side of a wall).
How can I flatten this out prior to laying LVP? I really don’t want to rip up the lino if I don’t have to.

You would use something like asphalt roofing tiles to flatten the area.  They are good shims and don't hold water.
However a better option would be to just install the flooring with the dip.   Most of the LVP I put down in basements says no underlayment (so there also should not be material to level the floor).    If you have vinyl sheets glued to the floor I would not consider that an underlayment and fine with leaving that given you don't have pieces sticking up.
The fact is the drain is there for a reason.   And the slope allows your whole basement to dry if there is water.    If you level the floor and get water you may have standing water in your walls for weeks.

Leaving the dip would void the product warranty I think, since it’s out of the product specifications. You don’t think it might cause failure in the plank joints leaving that much of a slope over such a small area?

@Silverart - if these are the pure vinyl planks (no cork or mdf backing) I have installed these on basements 20-30 times and have never leveled the drain.   If it is the cork  or mdf backed ones, I would return them.

You can fill in the dip with a feather finish leveler.
This leveler dries quickly. Can be used over vinyl and as the name implies can be feathered easily.
You choice of flooring is excellent.  The planks are 7mm thick, so they are friendly to floor imperfections. So don't worry about getting the floor perfect.

Oh this looks like it would work. I was nervous that concrete patch compound might crack in such a small area - it looks like Henry 549 is cement based, you wouldn’t worry that it might crack under the planks?

When mixed correctly, it is very dense and not likely to crack. I have used it on numerous occasions.
